# How to build xpath with arguments in WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

how do i build xpath with arguments in webdriver IO
I have to pass xpath as a parameter,something like this-
const xpAthForthePageMenuItem = "(//div[contains(text(),"" + PageToNavigateTo + "")])[2]"
Now- above variable is my actual xpath value whcih i need to pass to the elem const to be able to write the selectors-
const elem = $(xpAthForthePage)- what is the correct way to accomplish this?
how can i achieve something like this in webdriverIO?
please can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
const xpAthForthePageMenuItem = (PageToNavigateTo) => { 
    return  `(//div[contains(text(),"${PageToNavigateTo}")])[2]";
}

const elem = await ${`xpAthForthePageMenuItem('somepage')`};
await elem.click();
```